# How to set a property if not exists array in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

i want to add properties in array if a value not in the array.

```
// Create a node with an array prop
CREATE (n:Test { my_array:['a', 'b', 'c']}) RETURN n;
```

Here i would like check my_array values and add 'new_value' like 'd' which is not in the list.
Please help to add this attribute.

Comment: You might want to checkout https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.contains/

Comment: @utnaf i got below error in my community edition

Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'apoc.coll.combinations' (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
"RETURN apoc.coll.combinations([1,3,5,7,9], 3, 4) AS output;"

Comment: Of course you need to install APOC first https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/

Comment: Is there a way to control CQL it self

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Is any other way to add attributes by using 'SET' query.

Comment: CQL means cypher query and not using APOC function. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Without using APOC function you can check if an element exists in an array by using the keyword "in".

> 1. Get all nodes without the element "d"
> 2. Update the array by adding another array with one element ["d"]
> 3. Return node

```
MATCH (t:Test) WHERE NOT 'd' in t.my_array
  SET t.my_array = t.my_array + ['d']
RETURN t
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I can think of is this one:

Given this node

```
CREATE (p:Test {my_array: ["a","b","c"]})
```

you can run this

```
MATCH (p:Test)
WITH p, apoc.coll.contains(p.my_array, "d") AS propertyExists
WHERE propertyExists = false
SET p.my_array = p.my_array + "d"
RETURN p.my_array
```

Maybe can be improved but I think it kinda work.

As I said in the comment, you need to [install APOC first](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/), and use [apoc.coll.contains](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.contains/)